# Extracting Column values and storing it in an Array

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I need to collect the columnn values and store it in form of an array from spark dataframe. Just like we do with pandas data frame using `.values` function

I have tried using `.select().collect()` however it gives me empty rows

```java
X = XVAr.values
Y = DF.loc[:,'LTR'].values
```

the above is done for pandas dataframe i need to do the same in spark dataframe

I expect an output in form of an array `[[5,6,4,3],[3,4,6,5]]`

Comment: Show some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without any sample data. But your solution should work,

```
arr = numpy.array(df.select('LTR').collect())
```